# Qt framework QMYSQL driver not loaded error on my application

Tags: c++, windows, qt, oop, qt6

I have created an application using Qt framework, which is using QMYSQL as database.

While I am in the release build, the application runs well, but the thing is when I am running the .exe one alone (I used windeployqt.exe to get all of the necessary files for it to run properly), I am getting QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded. QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QPSQL. The thing is that I have all of the DLLs for mysql in the same folder as the application. I used mingw_64 as compiler. I am using Windows 11, Qt6

EDIT:
SOLVED: I downloaded the latest qsqlmysql DLLs files for QT 6.6.1, pasted them in the same folder as the .exe file and it worked.

Comment: For my installed Qt applications in the folder containing the executable I have 3 folders: platforms, plugins and sqldrivers.

Comment: I do have only 2 out of those 3: platforms and sqldrivers. What does your plugins folder contains?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I literally said all of the details, what it is confusing to you?

Comment: You need `qmysql.dll` in the `sqldrivers` folder (I suspect it is not the case right now since the driver is not listed in your error message) and the dlls shipped with MySQL in your executable's folder (those will not be installed by windeployqt, so it may be incorrect of you to say "*I used windeployqt.exe to get **all** the necessary files for it to run properly*"). Run the dependency walker on `qmysql.dll` to figure out what is left for you to install manually.

Comment: If it does not answer your question, you will need to supplement details as asked by @RahulKadukar: OPs for the question I linked or [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507822/qmysql-driver-not-loaded-in-release-working-in-debug) both explain or show the DLLs installed and where they are located, in short provide more details than you. You did not "*literally said all the details*"... Even what you think is unimportant may in fact be necessary for us to provide an answer.

Comment: I solved it. I went downloaded the latest qsqlmysql DLLs for qt 6.6.1, pasted them into my application folder and it worked. 
Link: https://github.com/thecodemonkey86/qt_mysql_driver/releases/tag/qmysql_6.6.1